# Python Beautifulsoup - Scrape elements from "inspect"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get scrape some data from [stockrow.com](https://stockrow.com/TEVA) using BeautifulSoup.

However there seems to be some diffrences between *inspect* and *view sourcecode* (im using chrome, but i do not see that being a problem for Pyton).

This is resulting in some trouble as the sourcecode itself does not show any *html-tags* such as `h1`. They are however showing up when i use the inspect tool.

**The part i am trying to scrape (among other things) - this is show using the inspect tool:**

```
<h1>Teva Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd<small>(TEVA)</small></h1>
```

**My current code, printing an empty list:**

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

class Stock:
    stockrow_url = "https://stockrow.com"
    url_suffix = "/financials/{}/annual"


def __init__(self, ticker : str, stock_url=stockrow_url, url_suffix = url_suffix):
    # Stock ticker
    self.ticker = ticker.upper()

    # URLs for financial statements related to the ticker
    self.stock_url = stock_url + "/{}".format(self.ticker)

    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(self.stock_url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser').h1
    print(soup)



    self.income_url = self.stock_url + url_suffix.format("income")
    self.balance_sheet_url = self.stock_url + url_suffix.format("balance")
    self.cash_flow_url = self.stock_url + url_suffix.format("cashflow")

teva = Stock("teva")
print(teva.get_income_statement())
```

Answer (score 2):

The page is dynamically generated using jscript and cannot be handled by beautifulsoup. You can capture the information using either selenium and the like, or by [looking for API calls.](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/web-scraping-discovering-hidden-apis/)

In this case, you can get for TEVA, background information using

```
import json
import requests

hdr = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}    
url = "https://stockrow.com/api/companies/TEVA.json?ticker=TEVA"

response = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
info = json.loads(response.text)
info
```

Similarly, the income statement is hiding here:

```
url = 'https://stockrow.com/api/companies/TEVA/financials.json?ticker=TEVA&dimension=MRY&section=Income+Statement'
```

Using the same code as above but with this other url, will get you your income statement, in json format.

And you can take it from there. Search around - there is a lot of information available on this topic.  Good luck.